# Why wget doesn't get java file recursively?

Tags: wget

I am trying to download all the folder structure and files under a folder in a website using wget.

Say there is a website like:

```
http://test/root. Under root it is like


/A

    /A1/file1.java

/B

    /B1/file2.html
```

My wget cmd is:

```
wget -r http://test/root/
```

I got all the folders and the html files, but no java files. Why is that?

UPDATE1:

I can access the file in the browser using:

```
http://test/root/A/A1/file1.java
```

I can also download this individual file using:

```
wget http://test/root/A/A1/file1.java
```

Comment: Are there links to the `.java` files?

Comment: Post the content of the index-file in /test/root.

Answer (score 1):

`wget` can just follow *links*.

If there is no *link* to the files in the subdirectories, then wget will not *find* those files. `wget` will not *guess* any file-names, it will not test exhaustively for filenames and `wget` does not practice black magic.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you can access the files in a browser does not mean that `wget` can necessarily retrieve it. Your browser has code able to recognize the directory structure, `wget` only knows what you tell it.

You can try adding the java file to an `accept` list first, perhaps that's all it needs:

```sh
wget -r -A "*.java" http://text/root
```

But it sounds like you're trying to get a complete offline miror of the site. Let's start—as with any command we're trying to figure out—with `man wget`:

> Wget can **follow links** in HTML, XHTML, and CSS pages, to **create local
> versions of remote web sites**, fully recreating the directory structure
> of the original site. This is sometimes referred to as **"recursive
> downloading."** While doing that, **Wget respects the Robot Exclusion
> Standard (/robots.txt).** Wget can be **instructed to convert the links in
> downloaded files to point at the local files, for offline viewing.**

## What We Need

### 1. Proper links to the file to be downloaded.

In your `intex.html` file, you must provide a link to the Java file, otherwise `wget` will not recognize it as needing to be downloaded. For your current directory structure, ensure `file2.html` contains a link to the java file. Format it to link to a directory above the current one:

```html
<a href="../test/root/A/A1/file1.java">JavaFile</a>
```

However, if the `file1.java` is not sensitive and you routinely do this, it's cleaner and less code to put an `index.html` file in your `root` directory and link to:

```html
<a href="/A/A1/file1.java">JavaFile</a>
```

If you **only** want the Java files and want to ignore HTML, you can use `--reject` like so:

```sh
wget  -r -nH --reject="file2.html"
### Or to reject ALL html files ###
wget -r -nH --reject="*.html"
```

This will recursively (`-r`) go through all directories starting at the point we specify.

### 2. Respect `robots.txt`

Ensure that if you have a `/robots.txt` file in your `*/root/*` directory it does not prevent crawling. If it does, you need to instruct `wget` to ignore it using the following option in your `wget` command by adding:

```sh
wget ... -e robots=off http://test/root
```

### 3. Convert remote links to local files.

Additionally, `wget` must be **instructed** to convert links into downloaded files. If you've done everything above correctly, you should be fine here. The easiest way I've found to get all files, provided nothing is hidden behind a non-public directory, is using the `mirror` command.

#### Try this:

```sh
wget -mpEk http://text/root/

# If robots.txt is present:

wget -mpEk robots=off http://text/root/
```

Using `-m` instead of `-r` is preferred as it doesn't have a maximum recursion depth and it downloads all assets. Mirror is pretty good at determining the full depth of a site, however if you have many external links you could end up downloading more than just your site, which is why we use `-p -E -k`. All pre-requisite files to make the page, and a preserved directory structure should be the output. `-k` converts links to local files.
Since you should have a link set up, you should get a `file1.java` inside the `../A1/` directory. However this command should work as is without a specific link being placed to the java file inside of your `index.html` or `file2.html` but it doesn't hurt as it preserves the rest of your directory. Mirror mode also works with a directory structure that's set up as an `ftp://` also.

#### General rule of thumb:

Depending on the side of the site you are doing a mirror of, you're sending many calls to the server. In order to prevent you from being blacklisted or cut off, use the `wait` option to rate-limit your downloads. If it's a site the side of the one you posted you shouldn't have to, but any large site you're mirroring you'll want to use it:

```sh
wget -mpEk --no-parent robots=off --random-wait http://text/root/
```